# How do i remove a password expiration policy?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, password

We had a password expiration policy recently removed from our AD but some users continued to get the "..your password will expire in x days. would you like to change it now?" message.

So we added a reverse/undo policy to correct the local registry settings

> Maximum password age = 0 days
>   Minimum password age = 0 days

This hasn't worked as new users still seem to encounter the above "change password" message sporadically. We have now removed all custom password policy GPOs and are left with the "Default Domain Policy". Still no good.

Can someone point me in the direction to fix this? And an explanation into what i was doing wrong (/how password expiration policies apply) would be useful too. thanks

Environment is 2k3 server with mostly XPsp2 clients.

Comment: why do you want to remove it? You can disable it for certain accounts but wouldn't disable it for everyone.

Comment: @Roy: I'd be happy it going back to the way it was before i added any expiration policy (ie. "Default Domain Policy" GPO w/no password expiry settings specified). Why? - i don't want passwords to expire atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember exactly, but from memory, If the user account has already expired they are marked in the AD db as such and need to be reset anyway even if you remove the policy afterwards.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. Can u link to doco?

Comment: No idea on documentation, IIRC I heard about it in class.

Comment: Ok. thanks. this seems likely to me. perhaps a flag i can access with ASDI Edit.

Comment: I didn't try to hack this manually. I just asked the affected minority group of users to manually rotate. Seems to have fixed it.

Comment: 0x00800000 ADS_UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED  The user password has expired. This flag is created by the system using data from the Pwd-Last-Set attribute and the domain policy.  If the password has already expired, this value in UserAccountControl will be turned on. 
Adding this reference for future use :D

Answer (score 0):

You must create/apply a policy to the OU in which the users are stored with a specific policy that explicitly disables the password expiration.

Comment: As i mentioned we did that ("So we added a reverse/undo policy.."). No luck.

Comment: Did you check id any other policy override this one?

Comment: Yep. I used the Modelling wizard